# ansible ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH collisions

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have multiple cloud projects utilizing bastion hosts, and in every project, my IP scheme is identical. (same network range).

I believe this is causing me a massive headache with templates and host variables.  When I run a ansible-playbook command against a single project or instance in a project, it works great.  When running against dozens of them, data gets 'crossed'. (the template for project 1 will get a variable updated with a value from variable2).  Its been driving me nuts.

I believe the problem is because inside the projects, I have many where the db server is 10.1.1.3.  I THINK this is causing ssh_control_path collisions, since the hostname it uses is probably NOT the ip of the bastion host.

Do I need to disable this feature entirely and put up with the slowdown? or is there a way to somehow add some extra entropy to the hash so it doesn't collide?

Answer (score 2):

I overrode the value in my host_vars folder. I use templates, but the gist of it is:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ControlPath="~/.ansible/cp/<project-Name>-%h-<server-Name>"'
```

This has fixed the issue, and I no longer have the controlPath getting re-used for different hosts.